# Difference between GetPixel and Canvas.Pixels in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Is the Api Function "GetPixel" faster than Canvas.Pixels ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GetPixel function is **very** slow! If you need high (or even acceptable) performance, you should use the ScanLine property. ScanLine[y] is a pointer to the yth line of pixels in the bitmap, encoded in the format specified by the PixelFormat property. For instance, for a 24-bit bitmap, the line has the format

B1 G1 R1 B2 G2 R2 ... Bn Gn Rn

if the width of the bitmap is *n*. Bi, Gi, and Ri are the blue, green, and red intensities of pixel *i*, respectively, as bytes.

Comment: @Ritsaert: Are you sure? I just created a small BMP file filled with (R, G, B) = (0xFF, 0, 0) and looked at it in the memory. See http://privat.rejbrand.se/hex.png. The highlighted byte is the first byte of the first scanline. To me it sure looks like the bytes go BBGGRRBBGGRR...

Comment: I am ashamed. You are correct. The format for the 24 bit bitmaps is in BGR order.

Answer (score 7):

It should be the same:

```
function TCanvas.GetPixel(X, Y: Integer): TColor;
begin
  RequiredState([csHandleValid]);
  GetPixel := Windows.GetPixel(FHandle, X, Y);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for something that performs better than GetPixel/Canvas.Pixel[] you should check out Bitmap.ScanLine. Only trouble is the data may be arranged in a number of ways, determined by Bitmap.PixelFormat